# Import and Export database in Mongo just like MySQL

Tags: mysql, export, import, mongodb

I am newbie to the `Mongo`.Before this I have worked only with `MySQL`.In MySQL we can `import` and `export` database easily.I want to know is there any option available in `Mongo` to `import and export database` easily.Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

If you look inside mongodb/bin folder (`ls -l`)
You can find a couple of binaries.

The mongoDB has import and export tools.

If you're running mongod locally on the default port, you can just do:

```
$ ./mongodump
```

Example: Dumping Everything

```
$ ./mongodump --host prod.example.com
```

Example: Dumping a Single Collection

```
$ ./mongodump --db blog --collection posts
```

Others like

[mongoexport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongoexport), mongoimport, mongorestore, bsondump etc.

for more http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to export:

```
mongodump -h yourhost -d yourdbname
```

And to import, just run:

```
mongorestore
```

It is important to remember that mongorestore just insert new documents, but does not update or delete the old ones. If you want to discard your database, you need to use the --drop:

```
mongorestore --drop
```

This is how I export and import databases like MySQL.

You can learn more about mongodump and mongorestore here:

[mongodump documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodump/)

[mongorestore documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongorestore/)